# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - add to existing value

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby

I have SQL (MySQL 5.x) query like:

```
           INSERT INTO table (val1),
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `val1` = VALUES(`val1`)
```

And this works fine.

Now i need to update it with a sum of VALUES(`val1`) + ruby variable.

```
           INSERT INTO table (val1),
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `val1` = VALUES(`val1`) + #{ruby_variable}
```

throws me an error.

(Ruby here is just an example, actually i need to sum VALUES(`val1`) + integer)

How it could be done?

Comment: more context please. Are you writing thi sin Ruby? Do you use something like Sequel?

Comment: show us a larger context

Comment: Updated with more details. Thanks.

Comment: Ok but the larger context => the one that involve some ruby code? how are you sending that query to your db?

Comment: The full SQL queries are a start, but we need to see how the SQL queries are built in your program. Please add the surrounding code and the full error message.

Comment: Octopus-Paul, well in this case it doesn't matter, because query like: INSERT INTO table (val1),
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `val1` = VALUES(`val1`) -- works fine. I have exception only when i try to sum existing value VALUES(`val1`) and int. For example: VALUES(`val1`) + 1 -- the same.

Answer (score 5):

Right at the top of the [fine manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) you will see an example of exactly the sort of thing you're trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

So you're looking for this:

```
connection.execute(%Q{
    INSERT INTO table (val1) VALUES(#{connection.quote(x)})
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `val1` = `val1` + #{connection.quote(ruby_variable)}
})
```

Where `x` is what you're trying to insert and `ruby_variable` is what you want to add to `val1` when there is a duplicate. You need a `VALUES` for the INSERT, not for the ON DUPLICATE.

Comment: Don't forget to escape `ruby_variable` in the second part.

Comment: @tadman: Thanks, at least I got one of them on the first pass. Of course, it would be nice if AR toned down the attitude and added placeholder support for `execute` like every other sane DB interface, then we wouldn't have to pretend that we're writing PHP in 1999 when we had to work directly with SQL. But now I'm starting to rant.

Comment: I haven't seen a good explanation as to why `sanitize_sql` is a protected method. I always have to work around that somehow either by using `send` or by writing simple class methods to do the escaping properly. Also I don't know if you've ever looked at things with the PHP tag here, but it's still 1999 if the questions and answers are any indication.

Comment: @tadman: "ideology" is the only explanation I can think of, the same silly reason that Rails still doesn't understand FKs or CHECK constraints. I've actually managed to pick up a bronze in PHP, shame that PDO use isn't more common.