# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - adding text onto existing value

Tags: mysql

lets say i have this column: "source". and in "source" i have already written "hello". when i upload something in the db, i want the previous value to be saved and i will just add onto what i already have, so the row will say "hello, there"

i have this query but it only works with adding as in math:

```
try{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO total_lb (ssn,date_added,first_name,last_name,company,address,co,zip,city,phone_1,phone_2,phone_3,phone_4,email,source)
    VALUES (:ssn, :date_added, :first_name, :last_name, :company, :address, :co, :zip, :city, :phone_1, :phone_2, :phone_3, :phone_4, :email, :source)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    source=source + values(source)";
    $query = $newpdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(
                        ':ssn' => $ssn,
                        ':date_added' => $date_added,
                        ':first_name' => $firstname,
                        ':last_name' => $lastname,
                        ':company' => $company,
                        ':address' => $address,
                        ':co' => $co_address,
                        ':zip' => $zip,
                        ':city' => $city,
                        ':phone_1' => $phone_1,
                        ':phone_2' => $phone_2,
                        ':phone_3' => $phone_3,
                        ':phone_4' => $phone_4,
                        ':email' => $email,
                        ':source' => $source
                        ));

                        }catch(PDOException $e){
                            echo"<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                        }
```

how do i add on words to already existing text in a column?

ive already looked at posts like: [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - add to existing value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608344/on-duplicate-key-update-add-to-existing-value) but it only covers math

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are trying to join text I will use something like (I'm adding a full example)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_tbl` ( 
    `id` INT (11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `value` VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `test_tbl` (`id`,`value`) VALUES (1, 'This is a ');

INSERT INTO `test`.`test_tbl` (`id`, `value`) VALUES (1, 'test') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value`=CONCAT(`value`, VALUES(`value`));
```

The trick is using the CONCAT in the on duplicate.

Hope it will help,
Liron